# Flutter upgrade error: Unknown flutter tag

Tags: flutter, flutter-upgrade

~ flutter upgrade
Unknown flutter tag. Abandoning upgrade to avoid destroying local changes. It is
recommended to use git directly if not working on an official channel.

i try to upgrade my flutter sdk to latest version stable "flutter_macos_3.13.1-stable", but i have error message : "Unknown flutter tag. Abandoning upgrade to avoid destroying local changes. It is
recommended to use git directly if not working on an official channel." Instead a successfully message .

Comment: See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/133441

Comment: It happens if you run flutter upgrade from the wrong directory instead of flutter install directory

Answer (score 126):

Run `flutter upgrade` from the flutter install directory. It works fine without the need to use `--force` or `-f` tags.

`flutter upgrade -v` for more verbose output.

Comment: There was an issue in the code itself, which is now fixed. But you'll still need to do the same to get the next hotfix release, which includes the fix for this issue.

Comment: just type cd then drag the flutter/bin folder which hold your flutter SDK. then flutter upgrade, no need to use --f or --force. When you force upgrade from outside flutter sdk folder. You cannot downgrade to previous flutter version directly by terminal anymore

Comment: I think that this error occurs for version 3.13.x

Comment: The command didn't work the first time even running it from inside flutter installed directory. I closed the VSCode where flutter directory was open and it did the magic. Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

Just run `flutter upgrade --force`

Comment: is it not dangerous ?

Comment: Blindly applying that mentality to everything is dangerous, yes... But sometimes it's necessary to just make things work.

Answer (score 12):

I found that running a Flutter upgrade inside the install directory worked for me...

```
flutter doctor -v
```

gives the version, channel and install location:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.2.0-26-generic, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
    • **Flutter version 3.13.0 on channel stable at /home/mark/snap/flutter/common/flutter**
```

Comment: Just out of curosity how is flutter emulator working on Ubuntu.
I installed flutter on Ubuntu once but as soon I was opening emulator there was a lot of lag.

Answer (score 6):

One reason to get this error is trying to upgrade flutter sdk from another location other than the flutter sdk itself.

1. Open the flutter sdk location from the terminal

   ```
   cd /<-- path -->/flutter
   ```
2. from inside, execute the upgrade command

   ```
   flutter upgrade
   ```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I tried to run the command in my project directory. The solution was to run the command `flutter upgrade` in the **directory where the Flutter SDK is located** (e.g. /path-to-flutter-sdk/bin/flutter).

Answer (score 4):

Save your changes of your current project, stash or commit and push to a git repo then just use:

```bash
flutter upgrade --force
```

Comment: Worked on macOS, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `flutter upgrade` from **Flutter install directory**.

---

To find its location, you can use `which` command on Linux systems:

```bash
mikyll@debian-EQPNRAP:~$ which flutter
/home/mikyll/Programs/flutter/bin/flutter
```

And `where` on Windows (or `which` as well if you have it installed):

```
C:\Users\mikyll\Desktop>where flutter 
C:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter
C:\Program Files\flutter\bin\flutter.bat
```

---

Once you found it, you can change directory and finally call `flutter upgrade`:

```
$ cd /path/to/flutter/
$ flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your working directory.

If you try and run the command "flutter upgrade",  not from within the flutter install directory. I find you get this error. I was in my code directory and failed... I changed back to my main Flutter install directory and all "flutter upgrade" command worked fine.

error: Unknown flutter tag. Abandoning upgrade to avoid destroying local changes. It is recommended to use git directly if not working on an official channel.

Answer (score 1):

It also occurred in my case, I solved it using below command:

```
flutter upgrade -f
```

or

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Both are same

Answer (score 1):

Use the force command or clone the flutter official repository. I think it is a temporary situation. Also after upgrading to 3.13 with the force command, we can update hotfix updates without using force. This is weird

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem because somehow my flutter repository is outdated. So I have to `git pull` and then `flutter upgrade` works again:

```
$ cd ~/flutter
$ git status
On branch stable
Your branch is behind 'origin/stable' by 12 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

$ git pull
...
$ flutter upgrade
(now it works)
```

Note: to find out where your flutter lives in, run `flutter doctor -v` and looking for 'Flutter version 3.13.6 on channel stable at'.