# "flutter upgrade" commands ends with an error "unknown flutter tag"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my flutter version by following command:

```
flutter upgrade
```

But it ends with an error:

```
Unknown flutter tag. Abandoning upgrade to avoid destroying local changes. It is recommended to use git directly if not working on an official channel.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76986997/flutter-upgrade-error-unknown-flutter-tag?rq=2)

You can try to run `flutter upgrade --force`