# Upgrading my flutter app is giving version solving failing error

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to upgrade my flutter app so I have followed a post here on StackOverflow but it is not working. I am getting the error below:

```
PS C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence> flutter pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies... 
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0.

Because deal_diligence requires SDK version >=3.1.3 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.3 <4.0.0'
```

This is what I get when I run flutter --version:

```
PS C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence> flutter --version
Flutter 3.13.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ff5b5b5fa6 (5 months ago) • 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

The posts say I don't need to upgrade my Dart SDK version but I only need to make the change in my .yaml file. I have done this but it is still not working.

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**
I ran flutter upgrade but now I get this error:

```
PS C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence> flutter upgrade
Unknown flutter tag. Abandoning upgrade to avoid destroying local changes. It is recommended to use gitdirectly if not working on an official channel.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dart SDK version is 3.1.0** incompatible with `deal_diligence` which requires **SDK version >=3.1.3**

You have to upgrade `flutter` and `dart SDK`

run the following command:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Your command `flutter pub upgrade` do the following:

> retrieve the highest available version of the package that is allowed by the version constraint specified in pubspec.yaml

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ran flutter upgrade but I got an error. I added it to the original post above.

Comment: See answers here may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/76986997/11217742@LostTexan